# HTML1701 on Windows 8.1 with jQuery, jQuery Mobile and Phonegap using Multi-Device Hybrid Apps for Visual Studio CTP2.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, windows-8.1, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I am developing an app using the Multi-Device Hybrid Apps for Visual Studio CTP2.0. I am using jQuery 2.1.1 and jQueryMobile 1.4.3. The app works fine in Android and iOS. I get the following error in Windows 8.1:

HTML1701: Unable to add dynamic content ''. A script attempted to inject dynamic content, or elements previously modified dynamically, that might be unsafe. For example, using the innerHTML property to add script or malformed HTML will generate this exception. Use the toStaticHTML method to filter dynamic content, or explicitly create elements and attributes with a method such as createElement.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=247104.

I have tried lowers versions of jQuery with no success.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Is the stated solution not working for you? `Use the toStaticHTML method to filter dynamic content, or explicitly create elements and attributes with a method such as createElement. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=247104.`

Comment: The error message appears without me including any code. jQuery/jQueryMobile throw the message. The app seems to work but I don't know what impact that error might have.